# Interaction MATLAB - ANSYS using Scripting

Tags: matlab, ansys

For those who have worked with SAP2000 and MATLAB, must know that it's "easy" to link these softwares with the API (MATLAB-SAP2000).

But in this moment I need to use ANSYS, and this software doesn't have API with MATLAB (That's what I know). So, in the documentation that I've found, there is a possibility to "link" these software, but I need to make an Script for ANSYS (Something with the APDL).

My questions are: Do you know places where I can find good information about making scripts for ANSYS?, Exist an API ANSYS - MATLAB? Do you know pages where shows procedures like I'm attempting to do?.

Any kind of information is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any API, but it is not so hard to connect the programs. A typical way to interact with Ansys from Matlab:

**(1)** Create your ANSYS script file (APDL), this basically should build your model, run the analyses, post-process the results and generate output.

**(2)** Generate input for the APDL script. It can be generated by Matlab, e.g. write txt files or directly modify the APDL script.

**(3)** Call Ansys from Matlab, example code to get the idea:

```
dos( ' "d:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v150\ansys\bin\winx64\ANSYS150" -b -dir "d:\ANSYS working folder" -i "d:\ANSYS working folder\project.inp" -o "d:\Working Folder\ANSYS working folder\project.out" ');
```

Where `project.inp` is the APDL script created in step **(1)**.

**(4)** Post-process the results generated by Ansys using Matlab.

**(5)** Repeat **(2)**-**(4)**

Note that the above steps are not the most efficient, but usually the FEM analysis takes significantly larger time.

The APDL language is similar to Fortran (or it is Fortran?) and an indispensable tool if you want to make some serious and/or parametric analysis.
Basics of writing APDL scripts:

[thorough introductory level guide](http://www.mece.ualberta.ca/tutorials/ansys/AT/APDL/APDL.html)
[intro book](http://www.padtinc.com/products/books/apdl-guide.html)
[official guide](http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_apdl.pdf)

The Ansys help is generally enough, it has scripting examples as well.

My experience is that typically the most time consuming part is writing the APDL script. If you are not familiar with the language it can be 'painful'.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this submission](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30887-use-matlab-editor-to-write-and-run-ansys-program) on the File Exchange, and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO7k4Umg2VE) on YouTube. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper Matlab toolbox available for free download from ANSYS Customer Portal that handles the ORB configuration in Matlab and simplify the access to a remote ANSYS aaS session. It is available for Matlab versions newer than 2014b though.

I will recommend:

- reading the ANSYS public blog post at [MATLAB Apps For ANSYS Products: Updated for ANSYS 17.0](http://www.ansys-blog.com/how-to-make-matlab-apps-for-ansys/)
- reading the Ozen Engineering blog post at [Supercharge your Simulation with ANSYS Matlab Toolbox](http://www.ozeninc.com/supercharge-systems-simulation-ansys-matlab-toolbox/)
- then install the helper solution from support.ansys.com  ("ANSYS as a Server Example: MATLAB Setup (MatlabR2014b-2016a)")
- refer to aaS chapters in the ANSYS documentation as needed

In terms of Matlab coding, if you have the solution installed it is pretty straight forward. Installing the solution takes less than 10 minutes, if you have access to support.ansys.com.

1. First you need to start ANSYS on the remote machine with aaS turned on (most common is to add -aas in the command line) and collect the aaS generated key file and bring it to the Matlab machine. By default the file name is aaS_MapdlId.txt.
2. Then you need to configure the Matlab ORB (two lines of Matlab code)

orb=initialize_orb();

load_ansys_aas();

3. Connect to ANSYS using aaS key file

   iCoMapdlUnit=actmapdlserver(orb,‘aaS_MapdlId.txt’);
4. drive ANSYS from Matlab machine, e.g:

   mapdlResult=char(iCoMapdlUnit.executeCommandToString(anyAPDLCommand))

Remember that all APDL commands are being executed in current working directory of the remote ANSYS machine. If certain files are stored in the Matlab machine, but need to be used on ANSYS machine, there are aaS commands that allow you to exchange files between an aaS client machine and the ANSYS machine.

This part of a more general API that allows remote calling of ANSYS (APDL) commands from any "CORBA friendly" programming language/environment (e.g. Matlab, C++, Java, Python...). In the ANSYS documentation is referred as aaS (as a Server).

If you have a Matlab version not supported by the toolbox, you will need to configure yourself the Matlab ORB. It is not difficult, but some people consider it tricky. If this is your case please post a new question and I will provide guidance in my answer.

Note: I am the author of the ANSYS blog post.

Sorin